# How to import numerical fluid particle data to Blender?

Tags: animation, mesh, particles, fluid-simulation

I have numerical files output from a c++ program for fluid simulation by solving Navier Stokes equation using particles, the file looks like this

```
-0.09 0.02 0.014737 1.26721e-17 4.34908e-19 -0.326667
-0.09 0.02 0.019737 1.02892e-17 2.54586e-17 -0.326667
-0.09 0.02 0.024737 1.08211e-18 3.22247e-17 -0.326667
-0.09 0.02 0.029737 -5.16105e-18 2.42116e-17 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 -0.040263 -7.48241e-18 -1.33054e-17 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 -0.035263 -1.51154e-17 -4.43992e-18 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 -0.030263 -1.83814e-17 -4.67568e-18 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 -0.025263 -3.33315e-17 -6.81458e-18 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 -0.020263 -4.54398e-17 -2.37933e-18 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 -0.015263 -2.15601e-17 4.90648e-18 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 -0.010263 -2.87995e-18 4.25644e-18 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 -0.00526297 7.32533e-18 8.69628e-18 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 -0.000262971 1.73026e-17 1.31652e-17 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 0.00473703 1.38162e-17 -5.92466e-18 -0.326667
-0.09 0.025 0.00973703 1.64762e-17 -1.85798e-17 -0.326667
```

Note the first 3 numbers are the particle positions, the last 3 numbers are velocities of the particles. What is the right file format to import to Blender for animation? I am trying to display or visualize the file (3D fluid) that is shown above in Blender and I am not sure how to do that.

**EDIT:** [mjf]  I would like to import the array as a collection of particles that represent the initial position and velocity of particles in a fluid flow and then visualize the state of the flow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?  As it is, there's no importer that will import data in the format of your file so you'd have to write your own, but to know what it would look like, we'd have to know what you want to do with the velocities and positions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for all your advice, I just edited the questions, does that clarify things a little bit better?

Comment: @MartyFouts Do you know what is the common format for visualizing fluid in Blender? Or files to import as fluid? Are they positions of the particles only or there are something else? Or if you can provide a extension name, that would be very helpful! Thank you very much!

Sorry that my question is vague, I am new to fluid animation as I am not familiar with data types for fluid simulation, so any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't.  Mostly people use Blender's Mantaflow simulator and it creates its own fluid particles.  I don't know how you would fit an existing array of particles into that simulator, sorry.  But now I do know what you want. I'm going to edit your question slightly to see if it will attract people who do know.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you, I appreciate your help! I am currently reading a fluid simulation book, and a few online resources, I will keep this post updated

Comment: just for my curiosity: i don't know if you have, but if you have all positions, you could just use e.g. spheres and then position them...or do you have just the "starting positions and velocities" and Blender should then calculate it?

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your comment. I thought about it too, I can just draw spheres around positions, actually I have a sequence of a flow, what I showed is just one file, so the data should be enough for animation. 

To answer your question, I just have the "positions and velocities" and I need to process that into a file format that Blender is able to work with..

Comment: but then it is just a "small" and easy python script you need. It should just read your file, convert that to positions/vectors and then you have just to position your spheres/metaballs or whatever you would like to have.

Comment: @Chris That sounds like a scatter plot, is that what you are suggesting? Maybe matplotlib is able to do this? Or if not, do you know any graphics libraries or examples that I can refer to? 

I will put this in the answer I wrote just now afterwards, many thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, what program are you using to generate your simulation data? Also, which book?

Comment: @MartyFouts The program I am using is from [here](https://cal.cs.umbc.edu/Courses/PhysicsBasedAnimation/): an introduction for physics-based animation. The source code of fluid animation, which just write a bunch of numerical data files. 

The book I am reading is: Fluid Simulation for Computer Graphics by Bridson, Robert.

Comment: There may be something in add-ons or in the works (Geo point instancing) that would be useful for you to import position and initial velocity, perhaps with geometry nodes and python.   I thought of this post when I read https://blenderartists.org/t/flip-fluids-addon-a-liquid-fluid-simulation-tool-for-blender/702503/1184

Comment: @james_t Thanks! I figured this out and will update my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, I read from this [post](http://rlguy.com/gridfluidsim/) that Stanford `.PLY` file can be used to work with Blender, and the particle positions are called "point cloud"!

What I did was using a python script to write the point clouds into a Stanford `.PLY` file using `open3d`, the code is given as follows:

```
def write(file_name):
    # file format: "fluid.iii.part"
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    name = file_name[:-5]

    n = len(lines)
    point_cloud = np.zeros((n-1,3))
    for i in range(1,n-1):
        position = lines[i]
        position_numeric = np.array([float(j) for j in position.split()][:3])
        point_cloud[i] = position_numeric

    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(point_cloud)
```

Then I import all the generated `.PLY` file into Blender to get the following results:[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Quite interesting and useful.  Thanks for the update!   Doesn't seem to use the initial velocities?

Comment: You are welcome! No, I didn't use the velocities, I've been doing research about this, it seems we only need point cloud only to generate mesh for liquid. I am trying to give them a mesh in Houdini, cause there seems no mesh generation in Blender. Anyways, I will keep updating if there is anything new!

Comment: I tried someting like this years ago based on Blender 2.7x. Back then, the particle system used to cache particle positions for every frame. These were stored in arrays accessible via Blender's Python API. Having loaded the simulated positions it was possible to animate the external simulation. I didn't find enough time to properly implement a stable workflow for this. Maybe the situation improved with all the progress in Blender's development. I'll try to find some time and see if I can find my code again!